# How works requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am newbie to programming and faced with this function:

```
function update(time = 0) {
    console.log(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
update();
```

Why in the function we declare the argument "time = 0" but when we   declare this function do it without arguments?

In what moment requestAnimationFrame assign new value to variable time?

Comment: `time = 0` is a default value, so if you don't pass anything, the value is zero

Comment: @Kai I think the confusion comes from the fact that neither of the displayed calls use `time`, nor does the `update` function use it except to log it...

Comment: The callback passed to [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Syntax) is given a single argument, which is a value indicating when the function was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `time` is has been set a default value of 0. Normally, the default value of a function parameter is `undefined`, but when declaring a function parameter with `param=default_val`, the parameter will instead default to the `default_val` if the function is invoked without the parameter or if the parameter is undefined. See [`Javascript Default Function Parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

The callback function passed to [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Syntax) is given a single argument, which is the time at which it was called.

Time will be `0` when `update` is first called because it was not passed as a parameter to `requestAnimationFrame`. After it is first called, the function passes itself as a callback to `requestAnimationFrame` and then the `update` function will be invoked with the `time` parameter, so it won't be set to 0.

```js
function update(time = 0) {
    console.log('time:', time, 'elapsed time ms:', time-start);
    if(time-start<=500){
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
};
var start = performance.now();
update();
```

A better way to write this code would be to use `requestAnimationFrame` to call `update` instead of manually executing it. This way, the first time the `update` function is called, it will have the correct value of time, rather than it being 0 (and there will be no need for default function parameters for the `update` function).

```
function update(time) {
    console.log(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: Did I understand right?
'RequestAnimationFrame' returns the time at which it works and matches with the frequency of the CPU with starting from now. This is the reason for the constant updating of 'time'.

Comment: @NikitaTrubchenkov That's close, but actually `requestAnimationFrame` does not return the time at which it works; it passes that time as the first argument to its callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `time` variable to count up as the animation runs, you can use this:

```
let time = 0;

function update() {
  time++;
  console.log(time);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/fyx74b1s/4/) of this code in action.

All `requestAnimationFrame` does is call the `update()` function to run again, so having `time++` will increase that value every time the `update()` function runs. If you declare the `time` variable inside the `update()` function, it will never increment, as it will be created as new every time the `update()` function runs.

If you want to read up on `requestAnimationFrame`, you can check out this [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Hope this helps :)